# Window not appearing in SDL2 (C++)

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have recently started a game project in C++ using SDL2. I have created a class for the Game and included an init function which initializes SDL and creates a window. My code complies normally with 0 errors and warnings. However, when I run the executable file, I am not able to terminate the program nor a window appears.

My Code:

game.cc

```
#include "Game.hh"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Constructing Funtions
Game::Game()
{}

Game::~Game()
{}

// Initializing Function
void Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{
  int flags = 0;
  // Check to see if Fullscreen Mode has been called
  if(fullscreen)
    flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;

  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 1) {
    cout << "Initialization Complete" << endl;

    // Create the Window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
    // Create the Renderer
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (renderer) {
      SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    }
    // Set Is Running to True
    isRunning = true;
  } else {
    isRunning = false;
  }
}

// Looping Funtions
void Game::eventHandler()
{
  // Initialize EventHandler & Get Event Type
  SDL_Event event;
  SDL_PollEvent(&event);

  // Process Events
  switch (event.type) {
  case SDL_QUIT:
    isRunning = false;
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}

void Game::update()
{}

void Game::render()
{
  // Clear Renderer
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
  // Render Shit
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Game::clean()
{
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
  SDL_Quit();

  cout << "Game Quit Successfuly" << endl;
}

bool Game::running()
{
  return isRunning;
}
```

Game.hh

```
#ifndef GAME_HH
#define GAME_HH
#include "SDL.h"


class Game {
public:
  // Constructor and Deconstructor
  Game();
  ~Game();

  // Initializing Functions
  void init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

  // Looping Commands
  void eventHandler();
  void update();
  void render();
  void clean();

  // Application Running Checker
  bool running();

private:
  bool isRunning;
  SDL_Window* window;
  SDL_Renderer* renderer;
};
#endif
```

And finally main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.hh"

Game *game = nullptr;

int main()
{
  game = new Game;

  game->init("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, false);

  do {
    game->eventHandler();
    game->update();
    game->render();
  } while(game->running());
  game->clean();
}
```

Any Ideas?

EDIT: found a fix to the issue, I made the public function `running` return the private `isRunning` variable. However, now the issue is that the code returns "Game Quit Successfully" w/out initiating anything...

Comment: Add compilation flag `-Wall` and you'll get a warning.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the error before trying `-Wall`, but a new issue arose. See the edit.

Comment: RTFM [SDL_Init](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init): *Returns 0 on success or a negative error code on failure*.

Comment: Well, changing the if statement containing `SDL_Init(...)` to initialize when it equals 0 seemed to work :) Thanks!

Comment: `SDL_PollEvent` returns 0 if event queue is empty - meaning it did not fill event with data. Reading event after that gives you garbage. Moreover, there may be multiple events in the queue, and you need to read them all - with `while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) { ... }`.